# How to skip validation in a validated field in one from conditionally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to save a  form for a model movie.But at the end of the form i have two radio buttons that when you click  each of them will show  extra hidden field(I hide these fields initially).User is suppossed to only choose one radio button to click and fill an extra given field(producer or director field).All the fields in this model are `validated_presence_of`.The problem is When you click on one radio button and fill out a given text field that means another field hidden in another radio button will be blank therefore the form wont get submitted(because of `validated_presence_of`).How do i go around this?Thank you

```
 <%= form_for @movie ,:url=>{:action =>"create"} do |f|%>
 <%= f.error_messages %>       
 <%=f.text_field :title%>
 <%= f.text_field :description%>

<%= f.radio_button :drama "drama" %>     
<div style="display:none"><%= f.text_field :director %></div>#this is displayed with javscript when you click radio button

   <%= f.radio_button :action "action" %>
  <div style="display:none"><%= f.text_field :producer %></div> #this is displayed with javscript when you click radio button
    <%= f.submit "post"%>
```

Model

```
      class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
       validates_presence_of :title
   validates_presence_of :description
       validates_presence_of :director
   validates_presence_of :producer
       end
```

Schema

```
      create_table "movies", :force => true do |t|
      t.string   "title"
      t.text  "description"
      t.boolean  "drama",                                     
      t.boolean  "action"
     end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're saying that all of the fields are required (all of them have `validates_presence_of`) and so your form won't submit because there's always one field that isn't present.  Of course it won't, in that case.

The obvious solution is: don't enforce the presence of every field.  Perhaps what you want is to validate that at least one of :director and :producer is present.  Take a look at [conditional validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#conditional-validation).

ETA: example

```
validates_presence_of :director, :if => "producer.blank?"
validates_presence_of :producer, :if => "director.blank?"
```

Comment: how do you do atleast one in my case? I am not sure how i can use `if` in this case

Comment: is it possible to do `validates_presence_of :director, :if => "producer.blank?" AND "title.blank?"`

Comment: You can do `:if => "producer.blank? and title.blank?"` -- i.e. the stuff in the quotes is just code.  However, this is meant to be used only for short bits of code.  At a certain point, you should consider writing a custom validation method (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html#creating-custom-validation-methods).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title
  validates_presence_of :description
  validates_presence_of :director, :if => Proc.new { |m| m.producer.blank? }
  validates_presence_of :producer, :if => Proc.new { |m| m.director.blank? }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look a [Conditional validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#conditional-validation) with `ActiveRecord` there you can have a custom validation and nested validation on the conditional validations.